# Jira with Github Integration

Tags: github, jira

Is there any option to have in a pull request on Github the actual Jira task url?
Basically now we can navigate from Jira to Github's pull request but from Github there's no option to navigate to the actual Jira task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if you can setup an [autolink reference](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-autolinks-to-reference-external-resources)

> Anyone with admin permissions to a repository can configure autolink references to link issues, pull requests, commit messages, and release descriptions to external third-party services.

You can see an illustration in "[Add magic links to GitHub: Jira, Zendesk and more](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/add-magic-links-to-github-jira-zendesk-and-more-3g17)" from [Davide 'CoderDave' Benvegnù](https://dev.to/n3wt0n):

[image: https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--HKr-HQfN--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/hjth4jab791zqq3vvmnh.png]

> In the form you have to specify 2 things:
>
> - the prefix, or keyword, you wanna use
> - the link to your service
>
> Note: the link must contain the variable  which will be replaced at runtime with the ID you are going to specify.